# Need to replace elements in a list using slicing

Tags: python

I have a list

```
w = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and I need my output to be like this:

```
w = [1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1]
```

I know the regular way to this i.e a for loop. Can someone show me how this is done using slicing? Any help will be appreciated.

For loop:

```
for i in range(1, (len(w) -1):
    if  i%2 == 0:
        w[i] = 4
    else:
        w[i] = 2
```

Comment: Numpy array or Python list?

Comment: Can you show the comprehension and loop?

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: It's just a python list.

Comment: Array means something else in Python. Please show how you did it before, and any slicing attempts you made, with a clear explanation of the error.

Comment: I added my for loop that works perfectly. I am not familiar with slicing.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace elements like this:

```
w[2:-1:2] = [2]*len(w[2:-1:2]) # replace 3rd, 5th, 7th and so on... element with 2 
w[1:-1:2] = [4]*len(w[1:-1:2]) # replace 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on... element with 3
```

edit:

I didn't mention that

- 3,5,7th etc. will not affect first, second and last element because
  of **[2:-1**

  and
- 2,4,6 will not affect first and last because of **[1:-1**,

  and
- step is 2 because of **:2]**

Answer (score 0):

It's such a strange request, but here you go:

`w = w[0]] + [4 if i%2 == 0 else 2 for i in range(1, (len(w) -1))] + [w[-1]]`

In general, every loop can be converted into a list comprehension this way, but in cases such as this, leaving it as a loop is probably more readable.

EDIT: You can also replace the `range` function with an enumeration of the elements to get the index, and ignore the actual elements, like this (note I also inverted the condition, since the new slicing moved the indexes by one):

`[w[0]] + [4 if i%2 else 2 for i, _ in enumerate(w[1:-1])] + [w[-1]]`